# How to use sed to remove newlines above and below a string?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I'd like to change all occurrences of `\ntoken1\n` and `\ntoken2\n` to `token1` and `token2` in a file).

I thought this would do it:

```
${
N
N
s/\ntoken1\n/token1/
s/\ntoken2\n/token2/
}
```

but it does not.

Thanks in advance for any clarification.

Comment: Is it a literal `\n` or an actual newline `LF`? ... I am now having a second thought about your requirement  ... I wrote my answer with literal `\n` as I understood it ... If a real newline, then @BeastOfCaerbannog add an answer for that and you have both ;-) ... My bad if I understood wrong.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a minimal testable example of input and desired output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to use `\n` as newline character in a `sed` command you have to use the `-z` flag, which separates the lines by `NUL` characters instead of newlines (`\n`). So the command you can use is the following:

```
sed -z 's/\ntoken1\n/token1/g;s/\ntoken2\n/token2/g' /path/to/file
```

where `/path/to/file` is the path to the file you wish to modify.

The above command will not actually apply the changes to your file. To apply the changes you can either redirect the output to another file as:

```
sed -z 's/\ntoken1\n/token1/g;s/\ntoken2\n/token2/g' /path/to/file > /path/to/another_file
```

or, if you like to apply the changes to the same file, use the `-i` (in-place) flag as:

```
sed -z -i 's/\ntoken1\n/token1/g;s/\ntoken2\n/token2/g' /path/to/file
```

---

References:

- [sed, a stream editor](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html)
- [`man sed`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/sed.1.html)

Answer (score 8):

Rather then treating the problem as a multi-line substitution, you might consider using the non-streaming [ed](https://www.gnu.org/software/ed/manual/ed_manual.html) editor instead, which provides a **j**oin command and supports relative addresses. Ex. given

```
$ cat file
abc
def
token1
ghi
jkl
token2
mno
pqr
```

then you can **g**lobally select token matches and then **j**oin each with one preceding and one following line:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'g/token1\|token2/-1,+1j' ,p Q | ed -s file
abc
deftoken1ghi
jkltoken2mno
pqr
```

(if your tokens are really `token1` and `token2` you can simplify the regex to `token[12]`).

To edit in place, replace `,p Q` (print then unconditionally quit) with `wq` (write and quit).

---

If you must use sed, then one approach would be to implement a loop:

```
$ sed -E -e :a -e 'N;s/\n(token1|token2)\n/\1/' -e '/\n.*\n/!ba' -e 'P;D'  file
abc
deftoken1ghi
jkltoken2mno
pqr
```

Here, `/\n.*\n/!ba` tests whether the pattern space contains two newlines (i.e. is three lines long) and if not, loops back and adds another line; otherwise `P;D` prints and removes a line *before* looping back. Together they maintain a 3-line sliding windows over which to apply the substitution.

---

Note: you haven't provided a test case, and in particular you haven't indicated the desired behavior in the case that `\ntoken1\n` and `\ntoken2\n` overlap ex. should

```
def
token1
ghi
token2
```

become

```
deftoken1ghitoken2
```

or

```
deftoken1ghi
token2
```

Comment: I am so bummed somebody beat me to ed man ed. I'm only 40, but even I have a lot of respect for ed and am glad somebody else thought of this too actually.

Comment: @JasonNordwick thanks ;) I guess I should have noted that `ed` loads the whole file into memory, so may not be the best choice for processing large files (although the same is true of solutions using `sed -z`)

Answer (score 4):

A backslash is used in ERE's to escape (strip special meaning from) characters in order to match them literally ... However, in BRE's, it also adds a special meaning to some characters.

So, it has a special meaning in both and therefore has to be escaped itself in order to be matched as a literal `\`.

`sed` has a `--debug` option that you can use to see what is matched in your `file`:

```
$ cat file
\ntoken1\n
\ntoken2\n
```

... with your RegEx patterns `\ntoken1\n` and `\ntoken1\n` like so:

```
$ sed --debug -e 's/\ntoken1\n/token1/' -e 's/\ntoken2\n/token2/' file
SED PROGRAM:
  s/\ntoken1\n/token1/
  s/\ntoken2\n/token2/
INPUT:   'file' line 1
PATTERN: \\ntoken1\\n
COMMAND: s/\ntoken1\n/token1/
PATTERN: \\ntoken1\\n
COMMAND: s/\ntoken2\n/token2/
PATTERN: \\ntoken1\\n
END-OF-CYCLE:
\ntoken1\n
INPUT:   'file' line 2
PATTERN: \\ntoken2\\n
COMMAND: s/\ntoken1\n/token1/
PATTERN: \\ntoken2\\n
COMMAND: s/\ntoken2\n/token2/
PATTERN: \\ntoken2\\n
END-OF-CYCLE:
\ntoken2\n
```

... to see that no `MATCHED REGEX` is reported.

While if you escape it like so:

```
$ sed --debug -e 's/\\ntoken1\\n/token1/' -e 's/\\ntoken2\\n/token2/' file
SED PROGRAM:
  s/\\\\ntoken1\\\\n/token1/
  s/\\\\ntoken2\\\\n/token2/
INPUT:   'file' line 1
PATTERN: \\ntoken1\\n
COMMAND: s/\\\\ntoken1\\\\n/token1/
MATCHED REGEX REGISTERS
  regex[0] = 0-10 '\ntoken1\n'
PATTERN: token1
COMMAND: s/\\\\ntoken2\\\\n/token2/
PATTERN: token1
END-OF-CYCLE:
token1
INPUT:   'file' line 2
PATTERN: \\ntoken2\\n
COMMAND: s/\\\\ntoken1\\\\n/token1/
PATTERN: \\ntoken2\\n
COMMAND: s/\\\\ntoken2\\\\n/token2/
MATCHED REGEX REGISTERS
  regex[0] = 0-10 '\ntoken2\n'
PATTERN: token2
END-OF-CYCLE:
token2
```

... then, you get a `MATCHED REGEX` and your replacement works.

To find and replace **all occurrences**, you'll need to set the **g**lobal flag like so:

```
sed -e 's/\\ntoken1\\n/token1/g' -e 's/\\ntoken2\\n/token2/g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk and only storing 1 line at a time in memory:

```
$ awk '
    /^(token1|token2)$/ { ors=ORS="" }
    { printf "%s%s", ors, $0; ors=ORS; ORS=RS }
    END { printf "%s", ors }
' file
abcdeftoken1ghi
jkltoken2mno
pqr
```

Comment: Okay ... So, basically, `printf` prints no line feeds `\n` by default but, you add it from `RS` before each following record (line) in `{ printf "%s%s", ors, $0; ors=ORS; ORS=RS }` ... That is unless `token1` or `token2` are found alone between line start `^` and line end `$` where you delay printing `RS` for an extra one record (two records in a row) in `/^(token1|token2)$/ { ors=ORS="" }` and at the `END { printf "%s", ors }`, you follow the last verdict on whether to print `RS` or not but after the record this time ... No doubt it'll works with actual `LF`s ... Am I right? :-)

Comment: @Raffa right, and yes it would.